# For emacs snippet, how to expand another snippet inside one snippet

Tags: linux, emacs, editor, yasnippet

I want to expand another snippet which is predefined into the current template file, how can I realize it?
For example:
Say I already have a snippet called 'snippet1', and I hope I can write snippet like this:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: snippet2
# key: snippet2
# --
`(expand 'snippet1)`
blablabla......
```

The string *(expand 'snippet1)* is just an example.
How can it be achieved?